# C++ Randomly select from string array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, random

I'm trying to devise a function that randomly selects three of the five strings and displays them on the screen. Here's what I have so far. It runs but nothing prints to the screen.

```
#include "BoxOfProduce.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>


using namespace std;

BoxOfProduce::BoxOfProduce()
:choices{""}, bundles{""}
{

}

vector<string> BoxOfProduce::randomize()
{
    srand(time(0));
    string choices[] = {"Broccoli", "Tomato", "Kiwi", "Kale", "Tomatillo"};

    vector<string> random;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        random.push_back(choices[rand() % 5]);
    }
    return random;
}


#ifndef BOXOFPRODUCE_H
#define BOXOFPRODUCE_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;


class BoxOfProduce
{
    public:
        BoxOfProduce();
        string getBundles();
        void setBundles(string b);
        vector<string> randomize();

    private:
        string bundles[3];
        const string choices[5];
        string random;
};

#endif // BOXOFPRODUCE_H


#include <iostream>
#include "BoxOfProduce.h"
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));

    BoxOfProduce bo;
    bo.randomize();

    auto vector<string> randomResult = bo.randomize();
    for (const auto& result : randomResult){
      cout << result << endl;
    }
}
```

I have updated my code now and still no print output. Although I am getting an error: 
**error: range-based 'for' loops are not allowed in C++98 mode**

I have never worked with **auto** before. So any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Why, ohh why, do people insist on using `rand` when it sucks donkeys balls so hard. Just use the `<random>` stuff already -*please*.

Comment: This shouldn't compile. In the function, `random` is local to the loop; it shouldn't be able to be returned outside of the loop. Declare `random` outside the loop, then remove the type from inside the loop.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Probably because `<random>` has a cumbersome interface, and `rand()` works fine for most people's cases.

Comment: Also, you'll need to make `random` a list of strings instead, and add to it instead of overwriting on each loop.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley `<random>` has a good interface, separating engines and distributions is a sensible design choice.

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury I didn't say otherwise. It is, nonetheless, cumbersome to use, as compared to `rand()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should not compile. g++ emits the following error:

```
return random;
error: could not convert ‘random’ from ‘long int (*)()throw ()’
```

The `random` variable is local to your for-body. You should give it a greater scope:

```
string random;
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    random = choices[rand() % 5];
}
return random;
```

To produce the 3 results, you need to return a vector of string like

```
#include<ctime>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<string>
#include<memory>
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

std::vector<string> randomize()
{
    srand(time(0));
    string choices[] = {"Broccoli", "Tomato", "Kiwi", "Kale", "Tomatillo"};

    std::vector<string> random;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        random.push_back(choices[rand() % 5]);
    }
    return random;
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));

    randomize();
    std::vector<string> randomResult = randomize();
    for (std::vector<string>::const_iterator iter = randomResult.begin(), iterEnd = randomResult.end();
           iter != iterEnd; ++iter)
      cout << *iter << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is only half the problem. This still won't do what they want. They want to return 3 values, but the loop currently overwrites the previous on each iteration.

Comment: @Carcigenicate you are right. I add your suggestion.

Comment: This is still not printing anything to the console. Just a blank console.

Comment: Are you sure ? I have tested it: I add the full code in the post.

Comment: @Codet I change my code for it to compile with c++-98. auto is specific for c++11 and higher.

Comment: @Franck okay I updated mine even more with the fix to randomResult

Comment: @Codet it is done. You should not have any more compilation error.

Comment: @Codet I have successully executed your code with the following modifications `BoxOfProduce::BoxOfProduce() {}` and the end of my post modified with `std::vector<string> randomResult = bo.randomize();`

Comment: @Franck nevermind! It worked! Thank you so much. You are amazing. I'm not high enough level to upvote this or I would.

Comment: @Codet The `for` loop I initially wrote was specific to C++-11. It aims to simplify the reading.

Answer (score 1):

The scope of `string random` is only inside the for loop in your code.
try this:

```
string BoxOfProduce::randomize()
 {
     srand(time(0));
     string choices[] = {"Broccoli", "Tomato", "Kiwi", "Kale", "Tomatillo"};
     string random = "";
     for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
     {
         random = choices[rand() % 5];
     }
     return random;
 }

 int main()     
 {
     srand(time(0));

     BoxOfProduce bundle1;
     bundle1.randomize();
     cout << bundle1.randomize() << endl;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided shouldn't even compile. Try this:

```
string BoxOfProduce::randomize()
{
    srand(time(0));
    string choices[] = {"Broccoli", "Tomato", "Kiwi", "Kale", "Tomatillo"};
    string random;    
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        random = choices[rand() % 5];
    }
    return random;
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));

    BoxOfProduce bundle1;
    bundle1.randomize();
    cout << bundle1.randomize() << endl;

}
```

The braces `{ }` define a *scope*. After that scope, the variables you define inside it are *destroyed*. So you should define that variable before you start that scope.

Probably the reason it compiled is that you already have another variable `string random` inside the body of the class `BoxOfProduce`. So you either define that `string random` outside the scope, like I did, or you just remove the `string` before `random`, and then the compiler will use the variable from the class body.